# Apache and mod_wsgi in deamon mode. No additional procces shown?

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I've succesfully tested and run a simple wsgi app in daemon mode by adding.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi_proc
WSGIProcessGroup  wsgi_proc
```

I would expect to have the new process printed out with

```
ps aux| grep wsgi_proc
```

However that is not the case, but the wsgi app is working fine.
What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation for the 'display-name' option to WSGIDaemonProcess.

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess